# Transition animation does not work in Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Could you please take a look at code snippets and let me know why the animation does not work, for example no opacity change and no background colour change. Please note that the  code is entirely taken from a book so I am really confused how it cannot work.

Please not that css file, angular-animate are included in html

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/simple.css"/>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

The body of html:

```
<body>
    <div ng-init="isShown=true">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isShown" />Show
        <div ng-class="my-animation-class" ng-if="isShown">
        <h3>Enter/Leave Animation</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

css code:

```
  .my-animation-class.ng-enter {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear all;
  -o-transition: 0.5s linear all;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s linear all;
  opacity: 0;
  background: green;
  }

  .my-animation-class.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  }
```

And please also note that ngAnimate is there as dependency in app.js

Please help! Thank you beforehand!Let me know if there are any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're using ng-class and passing my-animation-class as a scope variable, to solve this problem you should use

```
 <div ng-class="'my-animation-class'" ng-if="isShown">
```

or even

```
 <div class="my-animation-class" ng-if="isShown">
```

This way, your div will have the class and the animation will run.

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, however, I am afraid it still does not work (( By the way I have noticed that the .ng-enter and .ng-enter-active are not created when looking by the inspect element. However my book author do says that these classes are created automatically. Please let me know if you have any idea, I feel lost. Please see a cite from a book below:

Comment: When AngularJS inserts the template a class ng-enter is added. You can use this class to write your starting animation. Once the template has been added ng-enter-active is added to the element, which marks the end of the transition.